# When using terraform with heroku, is there a way to refresh app state after an addon is attached?

Tags: mysql, heroku, terraform, cleardb

I'm using terraform to set up an app on heroku. The app needs a mysql database and I'm using ClearDB addon for that. When ClearDB is attached to the app, it sets a `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` config variable. The app requires the database url to be in a `DATABASE_URL` config variable.
So what I'm trying to do is to use resource `heroku_app_config_association` to copy the
value from `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` to `DATABASE_URL`. The problem is that after `heroku_app` resource is created, its state does not yet contain `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`, and after `heroku_addon` is created, the state of `heroku_app` is not updated.

This is the content of my `main.tf` file:

```
provider "heroku" {}

resource "heroku_app" "main" {
  name = var.app_name
  region = "eu"
}

resource "heroku_addon" "database" {
    app = heroku_app.main.name
    plan = "cleardb:punch"
}

resource "heroku_app_config_association" "main" {
    app_id = heroku_app.main.id
    sensitive_vars = {
        DATABASE_URL = heroku_app.main.all_config_vars.CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
    }
    depends_on = [
        heroku_addon.database
    ]
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error: Missing map element

  on main.tf line 22, in resource "heroku_app_config_association" "main":
  22:           DATABASE_URL = heroku_app.main.all_config_vars.CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
    |----------------
    | heroku_app.main.all_config_vars is empty map of string

This map does not have an element with the key "CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL".
```

The configuration variable is copied successfully when `terraform apply` is executed second time. Is there a way to make it work on the first run?

Answer (score 0):

To get up-to-date state of the `heroku_app` resource I used the data source:

```
data "heroku_app" "main" {
    name = heroku_app.main.name
    depends_on = [
        heroku_addon.database
    ]
}
```

I could then access the value in `heroku_app_config_association` resource:

```
resource "heroku_app_config_association" "main" {
    app_id = heroku_app.main.id
    sensitive_vars = {
        DATABASE_URL = data.heroku_app.main.config_vars.CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
    }
}
```